# Simplify a if statement Python

Tags: python, if-statement

Is there a way to simplify this if-statement:

```
if self[by1,bx1]=='A' or self[by1,bx1+1]=='A' or self[by1,bx1+2]=='A' or self[by1,bx1+3]=='A':
```

coming from a class where self[y,x] fetch a data in a table.

The original code is:

```
for i in range(4):
                if self[by1,bx1]=='A' or self[by1,bx1+1]=='A' or self[by1,bx1+2]=='A' or self[by1,bx1+3]=='A':
                    print('There is already a ship here')
                    by1=0
                    bx1=0
                    self.placing_Battleship_p1()
                elif by1==0 or by1==0:
                    pass
                else:
                    self[by1,bx1+i]='B'
```

I want it to check if every position of my table are not equal to 'A' before changing them for a 'B'.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you could use `any` for this. This should be equivalent.

```
if any(self[by1,bx1+x]=='A' for x in range(4)):
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @GleyakiHope Great! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `any`, as Morgan Thrapp suggests. Or you could use `in`:

```
if 'A' in {self[by1,bx1+i] for i in range(4)}:
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a subset of the array since it is continuous, and use the in:

```
if 'A' in self[by1,[bx1:bx1+3]]:
```

eg.:

```
by1=0
bx1=3
a=[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [10, 10, 10, 10]]
print (6 in a[by1][bx1:bx1+2])
>>> True
```